# Создать загрузку path Pyside2

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2

Нужна помощь,
Нужно что бы по нажатию на файл в TreeView создавался путь к файлу и записывался в переменную. Так же что бы был мультивыбор. То-есть пользователь выбрал несколько файлов сразу и нажал кнопку PushButton и выбранные файлы сохранились в определённую директорию.

Пример кода ниже

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets   

import os

file = 'template'
path_dir = r'D:\templates'

class Ui_Form(object):

    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(1266, 798)
        self.treeView = QtWidgets.QTreeView(Form)
        self.treeView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 70, 611, 241))
        self.treeView.setObjectName("treeView")
        #-------------
# ?     self.treeView.QFileSystemModel.directoryLoaded('D:\test\qt')
        #-------------
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(670, 70, 131, 41))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.save_file)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 42, 541, 21))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "Form", None, -1))
        self.pushButton.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "PushButton", None, -1))
        self.label.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "TextLabel", None, -1))

    def save_file(self):
        print('File', file , 'saved in: ' , path_dir, '!')


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.resize(1266, 798)
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        # layout.addWidget(self.label)
        # layout.addWidget(self.treeView)
        # layout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.model = QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel()
        self.model.setFilter(QtCore.QDir.AllEntries | QtCore.QDir.Hidden | QtCore.QDir.NoDot)
        self.path = os.path.expanduser('D:')                          # <-- ('D:/test/qt')
        self.parentIndex  = self.model.setRootPath(self.path)
        self.treeView.setModel(self.model)
        self.treeView.setRootIndex(self.model.index(self.path))
        self.model.directoryLoaded.connect(self._loaded)

        self.dirictory = QtWidgets.QDirModel()
        self.dirictory.index(self.path)
        self.dirictory.filePath(self.dirictory.index(self.path))
        print(self.dirictory.filePath(self.dirictory.index(self.path)))



    def _loaded(self, path):
        print('_loaded', self.path) 
        print('++loaded', self.dirictory.filePath(self.dirictory.index(self.path)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
   import sys
   app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
#   Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
#   ui = Ui_Form()
#   ui.setupUi(Form)
#   Form.show()
   w = Widget()
   w.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, без вашего дизайна и на PyQt5

```
import sys
import os
import shutil

#from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets  
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.treeview = QTreeView()

        self.listview = QListView()
        # Это свойство определяет, может ли пользователь выбрать один или несколько элементов... 
        self.listview.setSelectionMode(QListView.ExtendedSelection)


        self.btn = QPushButton("Сохранить выбранные файлы в в определённую директорию.")
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self._on_btn_clicked)
        self.label = QLabel()

        lay = QGridLayout(self)         
        lay.addWidget(self.treeview, 0, 0)
        lay.addWidget(self.listview, 0, 1)
        lay.addWidget(self.label,    1, 0)
        lay.addWidget(self.btn,      1, 1)

        # установить нужный каталог
        #path = QDir.rootPath()
        #path = QDir.currentPath()
        path = "D:/_Qt/"

        # --- dirModel ---
        self.dirModel = QFileSystemModel()
        # setRootPath Устанавливает каталог, который просматривается моделью в newPath, 
        # путем установки на нее наблюдателя файловой системы.
        #self.dirModel.setRootPath(QDir.rootPath())
        self.dirModel.setRootPath(QDir.currentPath())
        self.dirModel.setFilter(QDir.NoDotAndDotDot | QDir.AllDirs)

        # --- fileModel ---
        self.fileModel = QFileSystemModel()
        self.fileModel.setFilter(QDir.NoDotAndDotDot |  QDir.Files)

        self.treeview.setModel(self.dirModel)
        self.listview.setModel(self.fileModel)

        self.treeview.setRootIndex(self.dirModel.index(path))
        self.listview.setRootIndex(self.fileModel.index(path))

        self.treeview.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)

    def on_clicked(self, index):
        path = self.dirModel.fileInfo(index).absoluteFilePath()
        self.listview.setRootIndex(self.fileModel.setRootPath(path))

    def _on_btn_clicked(self):
        listPath = self.listview.selectionModel().selectedIndexes()
        if not listPath: return False

        dirPath = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self,"Выбрать папку для копирования.",".")
        if not dirPath: return False
        self.label.setText("Выбрали папку: <b>{}</b>".format(dirPath))

        for row in self.listview.selectionModel().selectedIndexes():
            path = self.fileModel.filePath(row)
            if os.path.isfile(path):
                shutil.copy(path, dirPath)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w   = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]